# What's the best way to say "Nonna, I wrote this song for you"?

Tags: translation

I've tried a few translators which gave:

```
Grandma, this song that I wrote, is for you
Nonna, questa canzone che ho scritto, è per te.
```

Is there a better way (more fluent or common) to say this? I want to include that I wrote the song and that it's for her.

She was Calabrese, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

"Nonna, I wrote this song for you"? --> Nonna, ho scritto questa canzone per te